# Load more option in jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I get an error like this

```
SyntaxError: missing } after function body
```

Where did I make a mistake?

I would like to add the load more option in codeignitor. I got the code while implementing it shows this type of error.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    getcountry(0);
    $("#load_more").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var page = $(this).data('val');
        alert(page);
        getcountry(page);

    });
    //getcountry();
});

var getcountry = function(page){
    $("#loader").show();
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>welcome/getCountry",
        type:'GET',
        data: {page:page}
    }).done(function(response){
        $("#ajax_table").append(response);
        $("#loader").hide();
        $('#load_more').data('val', ($('#load_more').data('val')+1));
        scroll();
    });
};

var scroll  = function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#load_more').offset().top
    }, 1000);
};
```

Comment: I believe you need a closing brace the very bottom to close the `$(document).ready`. Try adding a `});` at the very bottom.

Comment: @aug ready() is getting closed before `getcountry` function.

Comment: @vignesh Try removing the comments from code once

Answer (score 0):

At the end of both your var you have `};` should be `});`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

getcountry(0);

$("#load_more").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var page = $(this).data('val');
  alert(page);
  getcountry(page);

});

var getcountry = function(page){
    $("#loader").show();
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>welcome/getCountry",
        type:'GET',
        data: {page:page}
    }).done(function(response){
        $("#ajax_table").append(response);
        $("#loader").hide();
        $('#load_more').data('val', ($('#load_more').data('val')+1));
        scroll();
    });
});

var scroll  = function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#load_more').offset().top
    }, 1000);
});


}); // End of Doc ready
```